# Create and agent based on another agent initial options nodeJs

Tags: node.js, agent

I have a library where I am making the api calls. The client used to make the calls is passed an agent created with `HttpsAgent` from `agentkeepalive`.

The edge case I am trying to handle is that when the endpoint that I am trying to reach matches let's say `https://somedomain.com`, because of SSL certificate issue I need to update the servicename/hostname of the request so it will go through.

The problem is that I know how to do that through `nodeHTTPS.Agent` and now I need to find a way to preserve the initial configuration passed to the agent in the first place. Consider this example

```
// node api
const response = await makeReq({
  ...etcOptions,
  agent: keepAliveAgent // agentkeepalive instance with some configurations
})

// now, in make request library
function makeReq(options) {
  if (options.address.match(/^https:\/\/(.*)\.somedomain\.com$/)) {
    // here, either I do something like, if options.agent -> options.agent.servicename = "*.etcsomedomain.com"
    // or

    options.agent = new nodeHTTPS.Agent({
      ...(options.agent && {...options.agent.options}), // trying to retrieve initial passed options for this agent
      servername: '*.etcsomedomain.com'
    });    
  }
}
```

Another problem is that passed `agent.options` strucutre might be different since that agent is created through a library that might differ from `nodeHTTPS.Agent`

Any idea how I can handle this edge case correctly?

Comment: That sounds awful. Why not fix the SSL/TLS error on the backend?!

Comment: Separate Client API that we have to use.. would've been the best solution